# How to work Google Vision Api with Php library by using uri?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-vision

I am working on Google Vision Api and I know how to send a request by using any image uri below.

```
`{
  "requests":[

    {
      "image":{
        "source":{
          "imageUri":
            "https://fallaviblob.blob.core.windows.net/createdblobs/20170601_191635_237.png"
        }
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION"
        },
        {
          "type":"WEB_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`
```

I want to use send request by using Php Client Library. When I look at the sample codes on Google Vision Documentation, it shows only sample for Local images of Remote images that work on Google Cloud Storage.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels#vision-label-detection-gcs-php

As you can see my json request, I need to use Php Client library with remote url but I couldn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [Image code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/src/Vision/Image.php) I believe you should just be able to pass in the URI as a string:

```
$uri = "https://fallaviblob.blob.core.windows.net/createdblobs/20170601_191635_237.png"
$image = $vision->image($uri, ['LABEL_DETECTION', 'WEB_DETECTION']);
```

Basically, if you pass in a string, it's treated as a URI if it can be parsed as a URI with a scheme of `gs`, `http` or `https` - otherwise it's treated as the image data.